# two classes referencing each other

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Say there are two classes, which need each other: *container* and *item*.
The class *container* creates instances of class *item*. Each instance of class *item* holds an instance of class *container* and needs to call only the method *method_called_by_item* of class *container*. Class *container* needs to see all fields of class *item*.

The problem is the forward declaration: I want to have a forward declaration inside of *item.h*, so that the class *item* can have a *container* as field and call the method *method_called_by_item*. How do I do that?

Class *container*, which creates items.

```cpp
// container.h
#ifndef CONTAINER_H
#define CONTAINER_H

#include "item.h"

class container{

public:
  item * create_item();
  void method_called_by_item(item * i);
};

#endif //CONTAINER_H
```

The implementation:

```cpp
// container.cpp
#include "container.h"

item * container::create_item(){
  return new item(this);
}

void container::method_called_by_item(item * i){
  // do stuff with item
}
```

The class *item*, which needs to call one method of *container*:

```cpp
// item.h
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <iostream>

class container;

class item{

public:
  item(container * c);
  void do_something();
  container * c;
};

#endif //ITEM_H
```

The implementation:

```cpp
// item.cpp
#include "item.h"

item::item(container * c){
  this->c = c;
}
void item::do_something(){
  this->c->method_called_by_item(this);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already added the forward declaration to <kbd>item.h</kbd> so all you need to do is add the following line to <kbd>item.cpp</kbd>.

```
#include "container.h"
```

<kbd>container.h</kbd> already includes <kbd>item.h</kbd> so you don't *have* to make any additional changes but as [Mahmoud Fayez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753928/845568) pointed out you can add a forward declaration there as well. This will remove the dependency on the header file which is typically desired - it can reduce build times on large projects and allows the header file to "stand on it's own".

Comment: Now, how do you get the destructors called when using shared_ptr now that these classes are referencing each other?

Comment: @James you'll need to either manually break the circular reference or use `std::weak_ptr` as appropriate.

Comment: Obvious I tried weak_prt and discovered there was no -> operator so I was unable to access any member functions. But I figured out what was happening. I did some more research and discovered that I should in fact be using standard pointers to pass into functions and maintain references to parent/child classes. Once I did that, the destructors started getting called.

Comment: @James There is no `->` operator for _good_ reason - you don't know if the weak pointer references a valid object or not. You need to call `lock` to get a shared pointer to the object references by `weak_ptr`. Using raw pointers here is a terrible idea and defeats the purpose of expressing and managing lifetime and ownership with smart pointers.

Answer (score 11):

in container.h

```
class item; // do not include the item.h
```

in container.cpp

```
#include "item.h"
```

in item.h

```
class container; // do not include container.h
```

in item.cpp

```
#include "container.h"
```