# C++ Two Classes Template Methods Reference (Not Compose) Each Other

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, forward-declaration

I've gotten into a bit of a design block in a C++ program of mine as two different header files are required to reference each other. Typically a forward declaration would be used here, but since both classes use template functions/constructors a forward declaration cannot be used as methods/variables from both classes need to be used.

For example consider the following scenario (this is pseudo code as an example, it may/may not compile. The objects are representative of my actual application so if a redesign is necessary then I'd love to understand the design philosophies of what I did wrong)

```cpp
// Application.hpp
#include <Assets.hpp>
#include <Logger.hpp>

class Application {
public:
    
    // Some brilliant code here ...
    Logger myLogger;

    template <int someArrayLen> Application(std::array<int, someArrayLen> myArr, SomeOtherTypes someOtherStuff) : myLogger(stuffHere) {
        mainAssets = new Assets(myArr);
    }

    ~Application(); // Assume this is implemented in Application.cpp and has delete mainAssets;
};

extern Application* mainApp; // Assume Application* mainApp = nullptr; in Application.cpp
```

```cpp
// Assets.hpp
// #include <Application.hpp> ???? The issue lies here

class Assets {
private:
    // Random data structures/stuff for holding shaders/textures/etc

protected:
    
    template <int someArrayLen> Assets(std::array<int, someArrayLen> myArr) {
        if (!shadersSupported()) {
            // Main app is an unknown symbol
            mainApp->myLogger->error("Your GPU is too old/whatever!");
        }

        // Random code for loading assets based on my template stuff
    }

    friend class Application;

public:
    // Get assets/whatever here
};

extern Assets* mainAssets; // Assume Assets* mainAssets = nullptr; in Assets.cpp
```

How can I fix the compile error regarding `mainApp` being an unknown symbol? Any feedback/help is appreciated, thanks!

I've already looked through all the following questions but none address this unique scenario:

- [two classes referencing each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753889/two-classes-referencing-each-other)

  - This question had no use of templates so forward declarations could be used as the method bodies weren't defined in the headers
- [Two classes referencing each other with hash template specialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585924/two-classes-referencing-each-other-with-hash-template-specialization)

  - The solution from this question cannot be used as here the compiler was unable to figure out how much memory to allocate, whereas in my question the issue isn't regarding the compiler being confused with how much to allocate but rather what to reference
- [Two template classes being composed of a member of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205367/two-template-classes-being-composed-of-a-member-of-each-other)

  - This question addressed a design flaw of circular dependencies which my application does not have, both classes are stored globally, they are just instantiated in separate constructors which reference each other.
- [Two classes that refer to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994253/two-classes-that-refer-to-each-other)

  - This question provides forward declarations as a solution which cannot be used here due to the requirement for using the class methods/constructors in template function definitions.

I've also already considered the following:

- Trying to change from std::array to pointers, this wouldn't work as my Assets constructor does rely on the lengths of the array.
- Trying to change from std::array to std::vector, I want to stick to aggregate initialization so it can be done at compile time, I believe vectors/lists would be too heavy for this.

Comment: You have cyclic dependencies between classes (Application depends on Assets which depends on Application). This is merely bad. OTOH a cyclic dependency  between header files is fatal. Fortunately you can forward-declare at least one f the classes instead of including its header. A call to `mainApp->myLogger->error` doesn't need to be a part of a template, so it can be moved to a .cpp file

Comment: So you suggest moving the logger call to a forwarder function which is defined in Assets.hpp and implemented in Assets.cpp then? That works since in this scenario I'm only using one function from Application.cpp, but in a scenario where more functions are used relying on forwards could get messy fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forward declarations will indeed work for your problem. The key is that function templates can be defined out of line (i.e., not in your `class ... { };` declaration) [legally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10535667/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-inline-keyword-with-templates). The same can be achieved for arbitrary functions using the [`inline` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method).

To now solve your specific problem, just split `Application.hpp` into `Applicaton_fwd.hpp` and `Application.hpp` - similar to [`iosfwd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iosfwd). `Application_fwd.hpp` contains almost all the code and `Application.hpp` includes `Application_fwd.hpp` and `Assets.hpp` before defining the `Application::Application` function template (just like you would define a function in a `*.cpp` file).

In `Assets.hpp`, you can simply use `Application_fwd.hpp` as long as you do not use the constructor. If you also use the `Application` constructor in `Assets.hpp`, things become a bit more complicated in that you need to very carefully consider all possible inclusion scenarios (i.e., what happens exactly every time one of your headers is included by themselves or a user) to make sure that it resolves in the order that you need it to without the guards causing trouble.

You can see it in action [here](https://godbolt.org/z/d1dn9PPb3)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you show a syntax example of how to split the definition of a class into multiple parts as unlike languages such as swift I don't believe c++ supports anything similar to extensions? So its a bit confusing to me how you could have the template constructor defined in a different header file than the rest of the class.

Comment: Ah whoops just saw the you can see it in action button, apologies for the other comment. I was unaware that one could split a template constructor definition like that, thanks for bringing that to light!